# Hamburger Side menu and Home Icons showing Imoji's while loading (Sometime)

Tags: hamburger-menu, home-button

Please see this image. On responsive website, the Side menu and Home icons some times shows as Imoji's. The icons used are from Icons library : font-family: feather

[See the screenshot of the situation in attached in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdeHT.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is the question? Did you want help with coding?

Answer (score 0):

Normally icon fonts are still accessible by letters, find the appropriate letter and set the button text and font.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "feather", size: 50.0)
button.setTitle("A", for: .normal)
```